# Wordpress query only shows first element of sub repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to loop through all advanced custom field post objects from another wordpress page. The loop only outputs the first post-object (event).

Maybe I'm not using the reset_postdata correctly? Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Thankful for any suggestions.

```
<?php $your_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=events' );
while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('events') ): ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows('events') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'single-event' ): ?>

            <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('event');
            if( $post_object ): 
                $post = $post_object;
                setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your first line be modified as follows..

```
<?php $your_query = new WP_Query( 
                          array(
                           'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                           'post_type' => 'events',
                           ));
```

and if you want to put wp_reset_postdata(), should be placed out of the while loop.

```
<?php while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('events') ): ?>
<?php while ( have_rows('events') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'single-event' ): ?>
        <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('event');
          if( $post_object ): 
            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
          ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: thank you, but this did not solve my problem. The content I'm querying is not a post_type but a custom field on the page 'events'.

Comment: Okey but this works for me for a custom page or post, any way if your query returns more than one results when you print $your_query->post_count; so that your query is ok the problems inside the loop, I just modify your code and update my answer.

Comment: it seems that your custom field 'events' is ACF repeater am i right?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot a line of code like setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); so I have modified my answer, could you try it again pls.

Comment: Thank you again @theva, however I dont think I explained the problem enought. What I need to do is get content from the page "events". This page contains a repeter with fields that are post-id. These post-id are event pages. When I fetch another field in the same repeter, it works, as it is not a post-object. However the post-objects seem to only show up once, and only the first object in the repeater.